# BadRequest for not required list

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a problem with my ApiController. I don't know why I'm getting an error 400 for not required list when I send empty NestedClasses or any empty property for NestedClass in request. I don't use DataAnonations attribute [Required], but response indicates that NestedClasses and all property in NestedClass are required.

```
public class TestModel
{
    public List<NestedClass> NestedClasses { get; set; }
    public string TestProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you for your advices.

Comment: net6? nullable feature enabled maybe, in that case this situation might happen

Answer (score 1):

To eliminate the warnings from nullable reference types, remove the following line from the yourproject.csproj file:

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the list nullable by using "?" so it will accept nulls.

```
public List<NestedClass?> NestedClasses { get; set; }
```

Also you might need to check the nullability of the properties in the NestedClass class to make them accept nulls.

Comment: Or `List<NestedClass>?`, to make the *list* nullable, instead of the contents